# Burned IC (Has something to do with USB)

Tags: microcontroller, integrated-circuit, schematics

As I was working on a project, I made a short and an IC caught fire and the magic smoke escaped. It was the IC U5 on the schematic (1). I am trying to find a replacement for it but I don't know what it does to search for an equivelant IC.

(1) https://robotdyn.com/pub/media/0G-00005516==SAMD21-MINI/DOCS/Schematic==0G-00005516==SAMD21-MINI.pdf

Comment: Except for that toasted IC, does the rest of the circuit work nominally?  U5 is a buffer with tri-state output, possibly.  Its purpose (together with Q1) is to select between external power supply and USB power supply.

Comment: U5 is a buffer circuit to perform OTG USB switch (change to device or host mode in response of USB ID pin status). It is very strange that this IC got smoked. You do have the schematics, don't you get any corresponding BOM which would tell you which ICs are there?

Comment: here is the schematic for a Sparkfun board ... it looks very similar .... shows part number `74AHC1G125` .... https://github.com/sparkfun/SAMD21_Mini_Breakout/blob/master/Hardware/Schematics/sparkfun-samd21-mini-breakout-v10.pdf  ........ datasheet https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74AHC_AHCT1G125.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Looks to me like a single gate CMOS tristate buffer, able to run from 5V, such as a 74HCT1G125.

It's job is to turn on the high side P channel MOSFET (Q1) so that the board's VIN (5V) power supply can drive out on the VBUS pin of the USB connector when the USB OTG port is in host mode and supplying power to an external device.

I don't like the lack of a pullup on its A and OE pins. See if you can bridge pin 1 to pin 5 with a 10k resistor when you rework it.

If you don't need host mode you could just remove Q1.

If you only need host mode you could remove Q1 and short across pins 2 and 3 of its footprint. Proceed with caution in this case, you'll release more magic smoke if you connect via a USB device cable.